# Parsing out text from string

Tags: perl, parsing, string-parsing

I have a tab-delimited file1:

```
  20    50  80  110
  520   590 700 770
  410   440 20  50
  300   340 410 440
```

read and put them into an array:

```
while(<INPUT>)
{
    chomp;
    push @inputarray, $_;
}
```

Now I'm looping through another file2:

```
  20, 410, 700
  80, 520
  300
```

foreach number of each line in file2, I want to search the @inputarray for the number. If it exists, I want to grab the corresponding number that follows. For instance, for number 20, I want to grab the number 50. I assume that they are still separated by a tab in the string that exists as an array element in @inputarray.

```
while(my $line = <INPUT2>) 
{
  chomp $line;
  my @linearray = split("\t", $line);
  foreach my $start (@linearray)
  {
    if (grep ($start, @inputarray))
    {
       #want to grab the corresponding number
    }
  }
}
```

Once grep finds it, i don't know how to grab that array element to find the position of the number to extract the corresponding number using perhaps the substr function. How do i grab the array element that grep found?

A desired output would be:

```
line1:
20 50
410 440
700 770

line2:
80 110
520 590

line3:
300 340
```

Comment: Is it possible that file2 is containning a number from second column of file1? For example 50,440,110 so on?

Comment: File2 only contains numbers that occur in column 2 and 4 of file1.

Comment: @user2674514: your example shows that *file2* is containing `20, 410, 700`, the numbers from *column1* of *file1*. Is `column 2 and 4` is the typo in your last comment?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it would be best to store the numbers from file1 in a hash. Referring to the example clontent of file1 as you provided above you can have something like below

```
{
   '20' => '50',
   '80' => '110',
   '520'=> '590',
   '700'=> '770',
   '410'=> '440',
   '20' => '50',
   '300'=> '340',
   '410' => '440'
}
```

A sample piece of code will be like

```
my %inputarray;
while(<INPUT>)
{
    my @numbers = split $_;
    my $length = scalar $numbers;
    # For $i = 0 to $i < $length;
    # $inputarray{$numbers[$i]} = $numbers[$i+1];
    # $i+=2;
}
```

An demonstration of the above loop

```
index:    0     1   2    3
numbers: 20    50  80  110

first iteration: $i=0
     $inputarray{$numbers[0]} = $numbers[1];
     $i = 2; #$i += 2;
second iteration: $i=2
     $inputarray{$numbers[2]} = $numbers[3];
```

And then while parsing file2, you just need to treat the number as the `key` of `%inputarray`.

Comment: `$i+=1` if file2 can contain any number. And you probably should check that `@numbers` has an `$i`th element.

Comment: @DeVadder: no it should be `$i += 2` because for each iteration, $i(key) and $i+1(value) is being used for `%inpurarray`. So in next iteration it needs to be started from `$i+2`. Did I miss what your wanted to point out?

Comment: Thank you DeVadder and Samiron. I think putting the first file into a hash and searching its key for the value was the right idea.

Comment: @Samiron: Yes, but i did miss that he said he only needed every second entry. I thought every number had to be both, key and value as i assumed every number could be looked up.

Comment: @user2674514 Welcome to SO! You may want to visit [**`about`**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page soon. If any answer worked for you, then consider accepting it by clicking on hollow green tick mark on the left top of the answer *(below vote up-down)*

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gets you close to what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my %follows;

open my $file1, "<", $ARGV[0] or die "could not open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";

while (<$file1>)
{
    chomp;

    my $prev = undef;

    foreach my $curr ( split /\s+/ )
    {
        $follows{$prev} = $curr if ($prev);
        $prev = $curr;
    }
}

close $file1;

open my $file2, "<", $ARGV[1] or die "could not open $ARGV[1]: $!\n";
my $lineno = 1;

while (<$file2>)
{
    chomp;
    print "line $lineno\n";
    $lineno++;

    foreach my $val ( split /,\s+/, $_ )
    {
        print $val, " ", ($follows{$val} // "no match"), "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

If you only want to consider numbers from `file1` in *pairs*, as opposed to seeing which numbers follow what other numbers without taking pair boundaries into account, then you need to change the logic in the first `while` loop slightly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my %follows;

open my $file1, "<", $ARGV[0] or die "could not open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";

while (<$file1>)
{
    chomp;

    my $line = $_;

    while ( $line =~ s/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*// )
    {
        $follows{$1} = $2;
    }
}

close $file1;

open my $file2, "<", $ARGV[1] or die "could not open $ARGV[1]: $!\n";
my $lineno = 1;

while (<$file2>)
{
    chomp;
    print "line $lineno\n";
    $lineno++;

    foreach my $val ( split /,\s+/, $_ )
    {
        print $val, " ", ($follows{$val} // "no match"), "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that both scripts above produce output that matches your test data.  You'll have to come up with more thorough tests to determine which script meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the input once but check for numbers a lot, you might be better off to `split` the input line into individual numbers. Then add each each number as key into a hash with the following number as value. That makes reading slow and takes more memory but the second part, where you want to check for following numbers will be a breeze thanks to `exist` and the nature of hashes.

If i understood your question correct, you could use just one big hash. That is of course assuming that every number is always followed by the same number.